# Get a specific word from a line read from a .txt

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, streamreader

right now I am reading some lines from a .txt.
Lets say, a user enters his name and in the .txt will be saved "Logged in {username} on 13/04/2016 at 10:55 am".
(Just an example.)

Now I want to read the .txt and print only specific parts into a textbox.
Meaning, in the textbox shall appear "{Username} - 13/04/2016 - 10:55 am".

So far, I am able to read from the .txt and print the whole line.

```
private void button_print_results_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;
    string actual_line;


    System.IO.StreamReader file_to_read =
    new System.IO.StreamReader("myText.txt");
    while ((actual_line = file_to_read.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        textBox_results.Text = textBox_results.Text +"\n"+ actual_line;
        counter++;
    }

    file_to_read.Close();
}
```

Is there a way, to reach this without overwriting the whole file?

And no, I can't change the format how the names etc. are saved.
(I used them here for a better understanding, the actual lines I need to read/check are different and auto-generated).

I don't expect full working code, it would be just great if you could tell me for which commands I need to look. Been a long time since I last worked with c#/wpf and I never worked much with Streamreader...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could split the `actual_line` String so you get an array of Strings. And then fill the Strings you want to show in the TextBox into it.

```
string[] values = actual_line.Split(' ');
textBox_results.Text = textBox_results.Text + "\n" + values[2] + " " + values[6] + " " + values[7];
```

The text in the TextBox for example is "*{username} 10:55 am*"

Comment: This is OK if the username does not contain space, other than that this solution would be valid

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of possible solutions for this. One most straight forward way for your case would be to use `Substring` and `Replace`.

Since the earlier `string` is always `Logged in` (note the last space) and you simply want to get the rests of the `string` after the phrase, replacing only the preposition of time words (" on ", " at ") with dash (" - ") you could take advantage on that:

```
string str = "Logged in {username} on 13/04/2016 at 10:55 am";
string substr = str.Substring(("Logged in ").Length) //note the last space
                   .Replace(" on ", " - ")
                   .Replace(" at ", " - ");
```

In your implementation, this is how it look like:

```
while ((actual_line = file_to_read.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    actual_line = actual_line.Substring(("Logged in ").Length) //note the last space
                   .Replace(" on ", " - ")
                   .Replace(" at ", " - ");
    textBox_results.Text = textBox_results.Text +"\n"+ actual_line;
    counter++;
}
```

(Note: the solution above assumes the `{username}` does *not* contain spaced preposition of time words - which would almost likely be the case for a `{username}`)

Answer (score 1):

I think regular expressions is the best tool for what you're trying to achieve. You can write something like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("Logged in (?<userName>.+) on (?<loginTime>.+)");
while ((actual_line = file_to_read.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Match match = regex.Match(actual_line);
    if (match.Success) {
        string loginInfo = string.Format("{0} - {1}", match.Groups["userName"], match.Groups["loginTime"]);
        textBox_results.Text = textBox_results.Text +"\n"+ loginInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Regex is the best way here, although if the date and time format is always the same, you may want to use a more specific pattern. I came up with `Logged in (?<username>{.+}) on (?<date>\d+\/\d+\/\d+) at (?<time>\d+:\d+ ?[ap]m)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex for better performances as @Dmitry-Rotay suggested in the previous comment, but if you jave a not-so-big file your loop+string manipulations is an acceptable compromise.

Always use Environment.NewLine instead of "\n", it's more portable.

```
while ((actual_line = file_to_read.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    actual_line = actual_line
               .Replace(("Logged in "), String.Empty)
               .Replace(" on ", " - ")
               .Replace(" at ", " - ");
    textBox_results.Text = textBox_results.Text 
               + System.Environment.NewLine 
               + actual_line;
    counter++;
}
```